# How can i display cards in grid view react?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am trying to populate a list of cards in grid view (10 rows by 3 columns) after retrieving data from mongodb. I have tried to implement a row with col-sm-3 but it doesn't auto-populate, may I know how can I do so from my current codes? I have also leveraged bootstrap for the cards.

```
receivedData() {
    axios
        .get(`http://localhost:8080/api/book/getallbooks`)
        .then(res => {

            const data = res.data;
            const slice = data.slice(this.state.offset, this.state.offset + this.state.perPage)
            const postData = slice.map(pd => <React.Fragment>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="card">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src={pd.imUrl} alt="Card image cap"/>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">example</p>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  </div>
            </React.Fragment>)

            this.setState({
                pageCount: Math.ceil(data.length / this.state.perPage),
               
                postData
            })
        });
  }
```

[image: It currently looks like that]

Comment: can you please use **className** on behalf of **class**

Comment: and for three column view you have to use col-sm-4 otherwise by using col-sm-3 you got the result with four column view.

Comment: if add sample in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) it's great

Comment: @KuldipKoradia changed to className still the same result

Comment: can you please generate a snippet for this? I think that you have to put <div className="row"> before you have start the loop and complete it by the end of your loop. right now I think <div className="row"> is inside of your loop and generate a single row for a single card.